# Video gets refreshed when clicked on submit button only on ipad

Tags: jwplayer

I m currently working on webcasting...my page consist of jwplayer, ppt slide and a question box.
I m facing trouble while live streaming is going, when someone sends the question the jwplayer restarts, **this problem only arise on ipad.**
its working fine on desktop and android phone.

Comment: Do you have a link? This is an issue that I am aware of, but it should have been fixed for 6.12.

Comment: I cant provide the link coz me and my team is working on it....providing link would also brk firms law.

Comment: The problem here is I have just joined the firm....previously they were using iframe for question box...but dey now want it to be built on html5...

Comment: I can't guess as to why it isn't working. I need to see something.

Answer (score -1):

```
    enter code here

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnsend" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" OnClick="btnsend_Click"Text="Send Question" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="s2()"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


Script:
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function s2() {
     alert("hello");
       $(':text').bind('keydown', function (e) {
        //on keydown for all textboxes
           if (e.target.className != "searchtextbox") {
               if (e.keyCode == 13) { //if this is enter key
                   e.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
               else
                   return false;
           }
           else
               return false;
       });
   };
    </script>
```

Comment: Above is the code for aspx button which is in Update panel of ajax and script .Still its not working for Ipad.

Comment: This isn't helpful. You are going to need to provide a link.